# How to refine the KQL search results filter by document content type?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, keywordquery

I need to refine the KQL search results that should return only Documents. Any Pointers ?

```
KeywordQuery query = new KeywordQuery(web);
query.QueryText = queryText;
query.Refiners = "IsDocument"; // No luck -> return all the results from sitepage, lists etc.,
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding to the `Refiners` property, do this

```
query.QueryText = queryText + " IsDocument:true";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SP 2013, better approach would be to use, "Documents Result Source" to return all documents. This result source has been pre-configured to filter all Document type like office docs and pdf.

Below is the way to set result source id for the query. The below id is of Document result source(OOTB). No need of refiner filtering.

query.SourceId = new Guid("e7ec8cee-ded8-43c9-beb5-436b54b31e84");
query.QueryText = searchText;

Hope this helps you.